# Canceling the last dictated words in dictation mode in iOS

Tags: ios, voice-dictation

In Dragon NaturallySpeaking one can use the `Scratch That` command to delete recently dictated text. Is there any equivalent  in dictation mode in iOS?

I unsuccessfully tried:

- Scratch That
- undo
- cancel

Comment: Shake the phone and press undo dictation, or hit backspace on the keyboard.

Comment: @kal-al thanks, one issue with  press undo dictation is that it would remove all dictated words and not the last ones. But it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS Dictation does not have the same voice actions as OS X, and is missing quite a few 'commands' such as the one you mention. Generally iOS Dictation is purely meant to transcribe the words you say and there's even very limited input for punctuation compared to OS X.